# Conscript won't install - what to do?

Tags: scala, scalatra, giter8

I'd like to started with `Scalatra`.  For that, I need to use `giter8` to generate a template project.  To install giter8, I need to install `conscript` first.  But doing that (at least using the runnable jar on Windows) fails with this error:

> ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
> ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
>
> ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
> :: net.databinder.conscript#conscript_2.11;0.4.4: not found
>
> ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

This is with the latest conscript version.  Doesn't it support scala 2.11 yet?  Is conscript even still actively maintained?  The mailing list is dead and there's not even a stackoverflow tag.

Although I'd prefer to fix the conscript installation issue, is there an easy workaround?    Like installing giter8 without using conscript?  Or setting up scalatra without using giter8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had an older conscript version installed that I didn't remove first.  Starting from scratch (deleting conscript and g8 installations) allowed me to install version 0.4.4 without this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Scala 2.11 is supported in conscript, so that's the first thing I'd try. Scalatra depends pretty heavily on conscript, so we'll need to check it out with 2.11 in Windows - I would imagine you're pretty much the first person who's hit this.

You can of course set Scalatra up without using conscript, by manually copying values around, but it wouldn't be very convenient. g8 definitely depends on conscript, I don't think you can have one without the other. The Scalatra crew will need to take a look at conscript and see what's going on here. You may actually want to file a bug on installation so that it gets looked at.

Comment: Actually, I had an older conscript (and g8) version installed before and didn't remove it before trying to install 0.4.4.  After deleting conscript and g8, they installed fine.